# How to debug your web deploy project

Tags: webdeploy

I have a webdeploy project and I need to check if a particular step has run or not.
I was told that there is some command that prints some given text in the log.
Does any1 has idea on how to do that?
to put in simple words : I need to write "Start" before a particular target starts and "Stop" after the target is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `<UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>` in your wpp.targets or pubxml it will include the full command line in the output window.

Failing that, you can enable diagnostic logging by executing the publish from the command line with a `/v:diag` argument.

If none of the above helps, you can [enable the MSBuild debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx) and debug the deployment interactively.